# Hive query performance is slow when using Hive date functions instead of hardcoded date strings?

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

I have a transaction table `table_A` that gets updated every day.  Every day I insert new data into `table_A` from external `table_B` using the `file_date` field to filter the necessary data from external `table_B` to insert into `table_A`.  However, there's a huge performance difference if I use a hardcoded date vs. using the Hive date functions:

```
-- Fast version (~20 minutes)
SET date_ingest = '2016-12-07';
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = TRUE;

INSERT
    INTO
        TABLE
            table_A PARTITION (FILE_DATE) SELECT
                    id, eventtime
                    ,CONCAT_WS( '-' ,substr ( eventtime ,0 ,4 ) ,SUBSTRING( eventtime ,5 ,2 ) ,SUBSTRING( eventtime ,7 ,2 ) )
                FROM
                    table_B
                WHERE
                    file_date = ${hiveconf:date_ingest}
;
```

compared to:

```
-- Slow version (~9 hours)
SET date_ingest = date_add(to_date(from_unixtime( unix_timestamp( ) )),-1);
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = TRUE;

INSERT
    INTO
        TABLE
            table_A PARTITION (FILE_DATE) SELECT
                    id, eventtime
                    ,CONCAT_WS( '-' ,substr ( eventtime ,0 ,4 ) ,SUBSTRING( eventtime ,5 ,2 ) ,SUBSTRING( eventtime ,7 ,2 ) )
                FROM
                    table_B
                WHERE
                    file_date = ${hiveconf:date_ingest}
;
```

Has anyone experienced similar issues?  You should assume that I don't have access to the Unix hive command (i.e. can't use --hiveconf options) since we're using a third party UI.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes partition pruning does not work when using functions in filter clause. If you calculate the variable in the wrapper shell script and pass it as -hiveconf variable to the Hive, it will work fine.
Example:

```
#inside shell script
date_ingest=$(date -d '-1 day' +%Y-%m-%d)
hive -f your_script.hql -hiveconf date_ingest="$date_ingest"
```

Then use it inside Hive script as  `WHERE file_date ='${hiveconf:date_ingest}'`

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have access to the Unix command line.  We're using a third party UI.  Still not sure why the two methods make a huge difference in performance.

Comment: Explain plan for both queries and compare plans and you will know.

Comment: What I would like to do is use the Hive date functions so that I could schedule the query every day to run (second version of the query).  But at the moment, the query is taking too long.  It's as if it were reading the whole table.  It seems that there's either a bug or I'm doing something wrong.  Why should it make such a huge difference whether I use the Hive date functions or a hard coded string?